# How to Display a Widget Over the Screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, snackbar

I want to Display a Widget like this over the Image/Screen:
[image]

I try to do this with snackbar with following code:

```
SnackBar(
  elevation: 5,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
  content: Children()
```

But it is displaying with a little black color in background...

Is there any other widget for achieving this???

If you know the answer of the question then answer this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use **Toast** in this case. A toast generally appears for 2 seconds or you can set a custom duration for the same.

**Flutter Toast** is a good library to achieve the same.

https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack(children: [
    ImageWidget(...),
    Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter
        child: SnackBar(
            elevation: 5,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
            content: Children()
)])
```

Comment: But I want to display it on click of button and only for some seconds

Comment: You didn't mention this goal in the description

Comment: then, I mean you need it https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars